(Python Ursina Engine) making a cube adaptively rotate to terrain
I would like some help with making a cube adaptively rotate to terrain, however, it seems to spin around rather than stay in a single place, and or contort in an entirely different direction. can anyone help me with this?
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController

app = Ursina()

# Creating a terrain
terrain = Entity(model=Terrain('heightmap', skip=4), scale=(128, 20, 128), texture='grass', collider='mesh', debug=True)

terrain.y -= 5

# Creating a player
player = FirstPersonController()
player.y = 5

cubeObject = Entity(model="cube", scale=(2,1,2), color=color.yellow)
rotationParent = Entity(model="cube")


cubeObject.y = 5
cubeObject.x = 0

def update():
    origin = cubeObject.world_position
    hit_info = raycast(origin, (0,-1,0), ignore=(cubeObject,), distance=0.5, debug=True)
    rotationParent.position = cubeObject.position

    if hit_info.hit:
        normal = cubeObject.position+ (hit_info.normal)

        rotationParent.look_at(normal,axis="up")
        cubeObject.rotation_z = rotationParent.rotation_z
        cubeObject.rotation_x = rotationParent.rotation_x

        #debugging out where points are
        entity = Entity(model="sphere",scale=0.3, color=color.red, position=normal)
        entity2 = Entity(model="sphere", scale=0.3, color=color.blue,position=cubeObject.position)


    else:
        cubeObject.y -= 1*time.dt

app.run()


Here's a nice solution to the problem, although this is only tested for a cube that was rotated. this may not work nicely with the terrain model or complicated meshes, but do let me know if it works nicely for other meshes
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController
from math import degrees, atan2
app = Ursina()


cube = Entity(model="cube", scale=(128, 10, 128), texture='grass', collider='mesh', debug=True)
cube.rotation_z = -25
cube.rotation_x = 30

cube.y -= 5

# Creating a player
player = FirstPersonController()
player.y = 5

cubeObject = Entity(model="cube", scale=(2,1,1), color=color.yellow, visible=True)
rotationParent = Entity()


cubeObject.y = 5
cubeObject.x = 0

grounded = False

prevWorldNormal = Vec3(0,0,0)

def update():
    global grounded, prevWorldNormal
    origin = cubeObject.world_position
    rotationParent.position = cube.position

    hit_info = raycast(origin, (0,-1,0), ignore=(cubeObject,), distance=0.5, debug=True)

    if hit_info.hit:

        if prevWorldNormal != hit_info.world_normal:
            prevWorldNormal = hit_info.world_normal
            norm = cubeObject.position + hit_info.world_normal
            print(cubeObject.rotation)
            print(degrees(atan2(hit_info.world_normal[0],hit_info.world_normal[1])))
            print(degrees(atan2(hit_info.world_normal[2], hit_info.world_normal[1])))
            cubeObject.rotation_z = degrees(atan2(hit_info.world_normal[0],hit_info.world_normal[1]))
            cubeObject.rotation_x = degrees(atan2(hit_info.world_normal[2], hit_info.world_normal[1]))
            print(cubeObject.rotation)
            print("this isn't repeating?")



        # Debugging where points are
        #Entity(model="sphere", scale=0.3, color=color.red, position=hit_info.world_point)
        #Entity(model="sphere", scale=0.3, color=color.blue, position=hit_info.world_normal + cubeObject.world_position)

    else:
        cubeObject.y -= 1*time.dt

app.run()

